# How to keep a form from submitting using javascript in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

My select tag is created using a rails view like so:

```
<%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-default', onSubmit: 'return stripDropdowns(this.form);' %>
<!-- I have also tried just on click event -->
```

The event fires. Currently I do not want to submit the form at all. Problem is whenever I click it the form always submits, even if I return false (using the `on submit` event). I have also used the `onclick` event, but the form also submits in that case. Now I thought it would not submit a form until I explicitly wanted it to by calling `form.submit`. My function:

```
function stripDropdowns(form) {
    alert('Test alert to make sure event is running');
    //Do stuff.
    return false;
}
```

Is there something in rails that I am missing about this that may be causing this issue? Or is my javascript just wrong? Hopefully someone can see something I am not getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to not use a submit button, but a 'normal' button:

```
<%# "button_tag(type: 'button')" creates at button that doesn't submit the form %>
<%= button_tag class: 'btn btn-default', type: 'button', onClick: 'return stripDropdowns(this.form);' %>
```

That way, you won't need to stop the form from submitting, because it's not submitted at all.

Comment: Good point. Didn't think of that. But what I don't understand is why every tutorial and answer uses a submit button? Apparently it seems it must have worked as they said at some point.

Comment: I'm not aware of the DOM-only solution for this. I usually use jQuery and `event.preventDefault()` to make a form stop submitting. Do you want me to edit the answer and add that as an alternative?

Comment: Ahh I see. It would be great if you added it for people having the same issue in the future. Seems jquery is overriding default behavior of a submit form (based off of the method name). But your answer was exactly what I needed. I appreciate your time :)